# actix web with mongodb project fails to build after an async call to mongodb is added

Tags: linux, mongodb, rust, actix-web

I'm implementing a REST API using actix-web and mongodb for the data back-end. I am using version 1.1.1 of the official rust-mongodb driver from crates.io and Rust 1.46.

If I add code to make a call to the mongodb collection to get records for example, even though `cargo check` shows no errors or warnings, `cargo build` takes a long time and then terminates with an error that it could not compile my project and a `(signal 9, SIGKILL: kill)`. After searching for the problem, I get that this is probably an out of memory error caused during the build/linking process. I am working on a Debian 10 machine with 16GB of RAM, so this is not very reasonable.

This only happens when I make the call in code inside a "handler" using `async` and `await`.

For example, if I try to get the names of the sample collection like so:

```
pub async fn samples() -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let dbnames = get_samples().await;

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(dbnames.unwrap()))
}

async fn get_samples() -> Result<Vec<String>, ServiceError> {
    let mut dbnames: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let client_uri = String::from("mongodb+srv://<...MONGODB_CONNECTION_INFO...>/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    let client = mongodb::Client::with_uri_str(client_uri.as_ref()).await?;

    for name in client.list_database_names(None, None).await? {
        dbnames.push(format!("- {}", name));
    }

    Ok(dbnames)
}
```

The `cargo build` will never complete and will stop with the aforementioned error.

Just to make sure, I used code to get the sample collection names, directly inside main.rs in the main function and it worked with no issues and the compile and build time were reasonable.

```
let client = mongodb::Client::with_uri_str(client_uri.as_ref()).await;
println!("Databases:");
for name in client.unwrap().list_database_names(None, None).await {
    for item in name {
        println!("- {}", item);
    }
}
```

Same result even if use `cargo build --release` to avoid having too much debug info

This only happens when using the async API of the rust-mongodb driver. With the sync API everything build and works properly.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the exactly the same issue after upgrade to 1.1.1 with async API. cargo build will never complete, it will consume 100% CPU and will keep consuming memory until exhausted.

Found related issues:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUST-558
- https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1688
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/75992

Two ways to workaround:

- Downgrade to rust 1.45.2
- Switch to async-std-runtime to workaround this issue. `mongodb = { version = "1.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["async-std-runtime"] }`

Comment: Having tried it with stable 1.47 and "async-std-runtime" it worked. Compiled and Built in less than a minute. Then I tried again with the default features for mongodb 1.1.1 in order to check if the upgrade to 1.47 had made a difference and had the same behaviour as with rust 1.46, a really long build time until it terminated with error.
So, apparently using async-std-runtime did the trick.

Comment: Yes,  if use default features need to downgrade rust 1.45.2.   And async-std-runtime works with 1.47